# c# parsing time series data

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am getting a JSON response from an external API and I am having a bit of a problem trying to deserialize.  Here is the JSON:

```
{
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2017-06-01": {
        "1. open": "70.2400",
        "2. high": "70.6100",
        "3. low": "69.4510",
        "4. close": "70.1000",
        "5. volume": "21066468"
    },
    "2017-05-31": {
        "1. open": "70.5300",
        "2. high": "70.7400",
        "3. low": "69.8100",
        "4. close": "69.8400",
        "5. volume": "30436364"
    }
}
}
```

Here are the classes that I tried to deserialize into:

```
public class StockQuote
{ 
    [JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")]
    public TimeSeriesDaily Daily { get; set; } 

}

public class TimeSeriesDaily
{
   public string Date { get; set; }
   public TimeSeries[] Daily { get; set; }
}

public class TimeSeries
{
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string High { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string Close { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
}
```

This deserializes as null.  I think that the class TimeSeries is correct, but I am not sure how to handle the changing date.  Using json2csharp does not create valid classes for me, it tells me the JSON is invalid.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That isn't a valid JSON structure and the TimeSeriesDaily class is also incorrectly structured. There is no array here. Arrays in JSON are like [ ]

Comment: I understand that is not an array, but I am not sure how to structure my class to deserialize.

Comment: It would be very difficult I think. Maybe dynamic parsing with Json.NET would be the way to go.. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing

Answer (score 2):

I am working on the same problem and wanted to post my solution. I used part of your code and completed it as follows. I think it works but I have only just started working on this.

```
class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd";
    }
}


public class StockQuote
{
    [JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")]
    public Dictionary<string, TimeSeries> tsd { get; set; }
}


public class TimeSeriesDaily
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public TimeSeries ts { get; set; }

}

public class TimeSeries
{
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public string High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public string Close { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
    public string Volume { get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a last right curly in the JSON, I think.

Comment: added the closing curly brace

Answer (score 0):

Beware that you're using non-standard names for your objects. Hyphens are not allowed in C# variables for example. Nor can variables start with a number.

The generated class should look something like this.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace kwcolson98
{
    public class StockQuote
    {
        [JsonProperty("Time Series (Daily)")]
        public TimeSeriesDaily _TimeSeriesDaily { get; set; }


        public class TimeSeriesDaily
        {
            [JsonProperty("2017-06-01")]
            public TimeSeries _20170601 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("2017-05-31")]
            public TimeSeries _20170531 { get; set; }


            public class TimeSeries
            {
                [JsonProperty("1. open")]
                public string Open { get; set; }

                [JsonProperty("2. high")]
                public string High { get; set; }

                [JsonProperty("3. low")]
                public string Low { get; set; }

                [JsonProperty("4. close")]
                public string Close { get; set; }

                [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
                public string Volume { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is correct, I think the actual JSON dates would change as time goes on so would only make it valid for that instance.

Comment: Then the correct way of designing the JSON is to make use of an array instead :)